# Issue with loading time of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app with more than 50 items in the list and the problem is My `RecyclerView` is opening too late (e.g. after 1 second when I tap to open it in another activity). I am using two `TextView`s and one image in a Card of the `RecyclerView`. The data is stored locally in Strings and the images are from the drawable folder. Does anyone have a solution for this?

I tried setting `hasfixedsize=true` but it did not work.

Here is the Adapter

```
public class HotelRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HotelRecyclerViewAdapter.HotelViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<HotelItem> mArrayList;
    public OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void OnClic(int position);
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClick) {
        mListener = onItemClick;
    }

    public static class HotelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTextView;
        ImageView mImageView;
        TextView star;

        public HotelViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            star = itemView.findViewById(R.id.star);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.OnClic(pos);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public HotelRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<HotelItem> items) {
        mArrayList = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HotelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hotelitem, viewGroup, false);
        HotelViewHolder viewHolder = new HotelViewHolder(view, mListener);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HotelViewHolder hotelViewHolder, int i) {
        HotelItem curretitem = mArrayList.get(i);
        hotelViewHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(curretitem.getImageid());
        hotelViewHolder.mTextView.setText(curretitem.getTitle());
        hotelViewHolder.star.setText(curretitem.getStar());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mArrayList == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return mArrayList.size();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `MainActivity` is like the following where I set the `RecyclerView`

```
mView = findViewById(R.id.recyler);
mView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mView.setLayoutManager(mManager);
mAdapter = new HotelRecyclerViewAdapter(hotelItems);
mView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The issue is happening in the emulator. Its working fine in the physical device.

Comment: After setting adapter no need to call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: already tried nothing changed data is static

Comment: How do you get the data from your local storage? And how much time that takes? I suppose, the data fetching from the local storage is taking the time here.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I am getting from array list like 
hotelItems.add(new HotelItem(getString(R.string.one),R.drawable.hotelartsbarcelona,"5- Star"));

Comment: Almost 1 second to open recyclerview activity

Comment: What about image resolution? Big images take time to render.

Comment: images are small with resolution 302*185

Comment: Comment the line where `setImageResource` is written and try just to be sure. Everything seems fine to me.

Comment: Remove the background color parent item of hotelitem.xml and then try

Comment: Did you try it on real device? The same issue?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov you are a life saver man worked smooth on real device

Comment: That is very useful to keep in mind if happens something strange try the same scenario on real device. Also keep in mind that something which works of Native Emulator could not working on Genymotion. I hope that comment also helpful for you

Comment: Where/when in the activity do you set the adapter on the recyclerview? In onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the image loading as you are setting the images directly to your `ImageView`. I suggest using `Glide` for loading images into your `ImageView` which gets the images in the background without halting the main UI thread.

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(getImage(drawable_image_name))
    .into(hotelViewHolder.mImageView);

// This is just a function for getting images from your drawables. 
public int getImage(String imageName) {
    int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

    return drawableResourceId;
}
```

To add Glide in your project, you need to add the following in your `build.gradle`. Please check [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for more information.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```